# Css help, report link

Tags: css

We are creating our articles page, and the MAIN div contains the article. I have done a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/UqwUp/1/

The issue I have ( hover over bottom right corner )

That link only appears if the user hovers over that particular area. What I want is the link to appear, if they mouse anywhere within the main div.

Its driving me nuts lol.

Any help appreciated.

To Clarify:

UNLESS you hover over the DIV , I dont want the link to be seen at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the CSS:

```
#mainPane .reportThisLink a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Which means the link is there, but in white. Set the color to something else :)

Comment: I dont want the link or text to be seen unless the user hovers over the div

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, you want to do `#mainPane:hover .reportThisLink a { color:#ec008c !important; }` instead of `#mainPane .reportThisLink a:hover { color:#ec008c !important; }`. Note though, that older IE versions do not support :hover on anything other than the <a> tag, so you will have to shim it with javascript if you go this route!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use javascript to catch a :hover event on that div, then make that link show up.
That would be the simplest thing to do, but if you don't use a JS framework on your website right now, it could increase page loading times.

Just an idea.

Comment: It's a simple CSS problem that Sajid identified. JavaScript is not the solution.